# 'DataTransferItem' is undefined in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I want to check if DataTransferItem object is present in the browser or not. For that I have written following code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  if(DataTransferItem)
  {
   $('#supported').show();
  }
  else
  {
   $('#notsupported').show();
  }
 });
```

Now I am testing with internet explorer 11. It throws error "'DataTransferItem' is undefined" and my script is getting killed. But that is what I want to test.

Comment: Use double-negation it casts to `boolean`. i.e. `!!DataTransferItem`

Comment: @Satpal That is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check it with the "window" reference as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.DataTransferItem)
    {
        $('#supported').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#notsupported').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation `if (window["DataTransferItem"]){}` or `Object.hasOwnProperty()` `if (window.hasOwnProperty("DataTransferitem")){}`